# Creating a club in Clubhouse for Win10 Club fails with error "Sorry, you can not create a club yet"

Tags: user

I have installed the Clubhouse app for Win 10 app I have my second user in clubhouse, so I am trying to make one club in it and get the below error:

```
Sorry, you can not create a club yet
```

[image]

If possible, I like to know it is related to being a new user as said
[here](https://www.saintlad.com/sorry-you-cant-create-a-club-on-clubhouse/) and if it is correct how much club I must join or days it must pass to can built one club?

Thanks.

Comment: The linked page seems to have all the explanations. For example `Clubhouse only grants the most active users the option to create their clubs on the platform. Try hosting more events on Clubhouse and join discussions regularly to increase your account’s activity. ` - are you an active user? Did you try the solutions on the page? Have you contacted the support as advised in the page?

Comment: I think I am an active user, but don't know how could I measure it? Also, as I don't use the android app, and I am only using the club win10 app, I guess it must be the reason. Additionally, I don't connected the clubhouse support page, but I wait for receiving some other comment and then will send this question link for them.

Comment: Just pointing out that you don't seem to be using Clubhouse app, but [Clubdeck](https://www.clubdeck.app/) instead, which says right on top of the page **Please note that Clubdeck is not affiliated with Clubhouse.**

Comment: This wasn't intended as a question to be answered here, but as a pointer that according to the page you're referring to you must actively partake. There's no published information how "active" is measured, so you have to ask them. What the "not affiliated" means is that Clubhouse support isn't likely to be able to even answer the question, they can only support their own app. So before contacting them, install their app and try again.